# How can I mock boto3 upload_fileobj?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pytest, boto3

I did:

```
mocker.patch('boto3.client.upload_fileobj')
```

but this does not work.  I can't seem to get the path right but this is how it's used so I don't understand.  Anyone mock this call before?

Comment: You need to have the full path to the method in patch. It would be something like: `some_package.some_script.boto3.client.upload_fileobj`

Comment: Side note: consider using `moto`, saves you lots of mocking/patching boilerplate.

Comment: @rdas I thought that `boto3` was the package.

Comment: @hoefling what is `moto`?

Comment: It has to the package where you are using boto3. Say if you're running "utils/file.py", then you need to mock `utils.file.boto3.client`. Check the mock docs

Comment: @rdas Oh yes, sorry I did try that but I still got an error `<function client at 0x7fb92d4697b8> does not have the attribute 'upload_fileobj'`

Comment: Impossible to tell what might be wrong without knowing the full context & test code

Comment: @Pittfall A library that allows you to easily mock out tests based on AWS infrastructure. https://github.com/spulec/moto

Comment: @rdas the reason `upload_fileobj` does not exist is because I didn't instantiate it correctly and I don't know how to mock that.  To make the proper object that has the `upload_fileobj` method, I need to do `mocker.patch('boto3.client('s3).upload_fileobj')`.  Again, that syntax is not correct and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You need to mock the return value of the client function. With something like `mock_client.return_value=MagicMock() ` where mock_client is the patched `utils.file.boto3.client`

Comment: @rdas I didn't explain that well it looks like.  The `upload_fileobj` attribute does not exist on `client` unless you instantiate it with `'s3'` so it has to be `boto3.client(`s3`), not `boto3.client`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct module path is "boto3.s3.inject.upload_fileobj":

```
import mock
import boto3

with mock.patch('boto3.s3.inject.upload_fileobj'):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Bucket('my-bucket').upload_fileobj(open('file.png', 'rb'), 'filename')
```

However, in many situations I think you'll find mocking AWS operations to be much easier with Moto: https://pypi.org/project/moto/